# Buildroot on Raspberry, IPE R2

Tags: software-installation

I've just installd IPE R2 (http://nutcom.hu/ipe-r2/) a Raspberry OS based on Buildroot.

How can i install a packet manager or install binaries?
May I use the SDK or i can even use the SSH Shell?

Answer (score 1):

[Buildroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UClibc#BUILDROOT) itself doesn't have a package manager because it isn't a distribution, although it could be used to create one, as appears to be the case here.

I don't see anything on the IPE website to indicate that they do use a package manager (their own, or someone else's), however, I do notice they have a contact email and surely your best bet is to ask them directly.  If it turns out that they do, please come back and provide a better answer to your question!

The goal of producing a read-only system for use in embedded contexts where that level of (uber-paranoid) robustness is required might imply that casual network installation of software isn't desirable, so don't be surprised if you are on your own with that.  If I were working on something like this, I'd get a prototype working using something more general purpose first (raspbian, etc.) so that I knew exactly what I needed, and then implement it with the IPE SDK. With regard to updating production systems via a network, it should not be too hard to come up with something custom for exactly that.